# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied {Python}

Tags: python, windows, restrict, system32

I'm making a file injection program via FTP
{User runs program, ftp downloads another program to a distant folder and runs that program}
When I try to make a zip file in my system 32 fold python yells at me and says YOU CANT DO THAT!

Is there a module I can use to get around this?
Thanks here is my code

`l_zipfile = open("C:\\Program Files\\"+zipfilename, 'w'`

Comment: Try compiling it with py2exe then run as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

That's an operating-system level protection.  If there were a module to get around the problems, Windows sucks more than I think it does, which is a lot.

Write to a different directory.

Comment: Please keep your opinions about windows to yourself.

Comment: @P'sao - I am tempted to reply "Please keep your opinions about my keeping my opinions about Windows to myself to yourself." but I'll content myself with saying one, I cannot say for certain that there isn't a module out there that breaks Windows "security" and two, I based my evaluation on 20+ years of working with both DOS (and it's descendants) and with Unix (and it's descendants). On what experience or information did you base your comment on?

Comment: Like i said that it is your opinion with your experiences. On the other hand I have my opinion with my experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Compile it with py2exe then run as Administrator. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions from the forum in this link:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10416349

"I downloaded Virtual CloneDrive (google it - its freeware) When I installed Virtual CloneDrive, I associated the .iso files with it and no others. I then ran the .iso file that I originally downloaded to make my disc, directly from my Program Files folder by double-clicking. It should be mounted and launch as a virtual drive and run like the disc but without using the disc. I think the access denied error has something to do with the disc drive but I was unable to fix it."